# chmod でファイルを '-rwxrwxrwx' の状態にするには？

Tags: linux

端末で `ls -l` を実行したとき、仮にそのディレクトリの中に　`p1`（ファイル名）があったとして、はじめ、p1が `-rw-r--r--` の状態にあり、そこからいろいろ調べた結果、`$ chmod 755 p1` を行うことは知り、実行したところ `-rwxr-xr-x` となったのですが、 `-rwxrwxrwx` の状態にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ファイルパーミッションを`-rwxrwxrwx`にするのはたいへん危険です。なぜそのようなことをしたいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ls で表示される `-rwxrwxrwx` の部分は **パーミッション** (=アクセス権限) を表しており、右端から3桁ごとに区切って読み取ります。(10桁目の `-` のみ特殊で、ディレクトリを表すときのみ `d` になります)

r, w, x で表す3桁は、それぞれ 4, 2, 1 の重み付けをすることで8進数の数値表記に置き換える事ができます。

```
---------------
rwx | rwx | rwx
---------------
421 | 421 | 421
---------------
```

`chmod 755 FILE` を実行した結果が `rwxr-xr-x` になるのは、以下の通りです。

```
---------------
rwx | r-x | r-x
---------------
421 | 401 | 401
---------------
 7  |  5  |  5  (例: 7 = 4 + 2 + 1, 5 = 4 + 0 + 1)
---------------
```

---

質問に戻って、 `-rwxrwxrwx` の状態にするには `chmod 777 FILE` を実行すればよいのですが、この権限は
**すべてのユーザーに何でも許可する** ことを意味するので、コメントでも指摘のある通り大変危険です。

`-rwxrwxrwx (777)` にすることでどんな影響があるのかを十分に理解していないのであれば、安易に設定することは避けてください。

**参考:**

[【 chmod 】コマンド――ファイル／ディレクトリのパーミッション（許可属性）を変更する - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1605/23/news020.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「-rwxrwxrwx」に設定することは、ユーザーになんでも許可するとの意味で、大変危険な行為だということらしいので、ご指摘通りそれに設定することは避けておきます。